# Query updating the column to null,overriding the existing value

Tags: sql, db2

Need a help.Below is the query which I am running in DB2. If the inner query from which I am getting the value to be updated is not returning the value the column is getting set to null overriding the previous value.Is there a way to avoid this and retain the previous value if the select query returns null

```
UPDATE
   EMPLOYEE demo  
SET
   demo.PREFERREDTELEPHONE =  (SELECT
      CONCAT(TRIM(ph.PHONENUMBER),
      TRIM(ph.PHONEAREACODE))  
   FROM
      EVIDENCE ed  
   JOIN
      CONCERNROLEPHONENUMBER cnum 
         ON cnum.CONCERNROLEID = ed.PARTICIPANTID  
   JOIN
      PHONENUMBER ph 
         ON ph.PHONENUMBERID = cnum.PHONENUMBERID   
   WHERE
      ed.CASEID =  demo.INTEGRATEDCASEID   
      AND ed.PARTICIPANTID= demo.PARTICIPANTID 
      AND ed.EVIDENCETYPE = 'PDC0000256'     
      AND  ed.STATUSCODE = 'EDS1'  
      AND ed.LASTWRITTEN = (
         SELECT
            MAX(ed1.LASTWRITTEN) 
         FROM
            EVIDENCE ed1 
         WHERE
            ed1.CASEID=ed.CASEID   
            AND ed1.PARTICIPANTID=ed.PARTICIPANTID 
            AND ed1.EVIDENCETYPE = 'PDC0000256'     
            AND ed1.STATUSCODE = 'EDS1'
      )    FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
)
```

Comment: COALESCE could be used to set a certain value (old content) when something else (your query) returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options

Use `COALESCE()` to replace the NULL with the current value

```
update mytable
set fld = coalesce(select<....>, fld)
where...
```

Only update the rows that have a match

```
update mytable A
set fld = (select myvalue from myfile B where a.key = b.key)
where exists (select * from myfile B where a.key = b.key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Agree Charles, you can use ifnull too

```
 update mytable
 set fld = ifnull(select<....>, fld)
 where...
```